Why does the getattr(ClassInstance, "http_method_names", []) function in django APIView return all http methods even though only GET is implemented?
I have a view being inherited by APIView and I have only implemented the GET method in it.
class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        # do something

But when I call getattr(ClassInstance, "http_method_names", []) I get list of all the HTTP methods even though they are not implemented.

I can not reproduce: I get ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] if I use MyView()._allowed_methods()

are you sure you initialize the correct view?

It was in fact another method that was updating the original result of _allowed_methods(). getattr(ClassInstance, "http_method_names", []) returns all the http views regardless of whether they are implemented or not.

But http_method_names exactly has that puprose:it lists all the HTTP methods one can do, not per se the ones allowed.

The .http_method_names [Django-doc] is an attribute that, by default lists all HTTP methods, so:

["get", "post", "put", "patch", "delete", "head", "options", "trace"]


Normally it will always return that list, unless you override it. This can be useful if you inherit from a view that for example has defined a .post(…) method, but you don't want to expose that, like:
class MyView(SomethingWithPostMethodView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'options']

    def get(self, request, id):
        # …
        pass
Or you could, technically speaking, expand the http_method_names list with an custom method, although I would strongly advise not to do this.
In order to find out what methods the view implements, you can use the _allowed_methods(…), which thus checks if the corresponding .get(…) method is allowed or not.
You thus can not introspect the methods allowed with:
getattr(ClassInstance, "http_method_names", [])

You can just create an instance and work with _allowed_methods():
ClassInstance()._allowed_method()

If ClassInstance is thus a reference to the type itself, or use ClassInstance._allowed_method() if it is a view object already.
